# Tool bar JavaScript Pin to / Onmouseover event conflict

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I'm making a tool bar with JavaScript. This tool bar's regular height is 50px. On mouse over, it's height changes to 500px. On this toolbar however, there's a little pin to image. My intention is to make this image change the tool bar div's height to 500px and let it stay that way. Currently I can change the tool bar div with the image, but onmouseout it changes back to its original 50px height.

How can I make it so that when the pin image is clicked, the onmouseout functions stops working until the image is clicked again?

If it helps, this is my code:

```
//Pin to Image

<img class="pin" onClick = "document.getElementById('toolbar').style.height
= '500px';" src="images/pin.png" width="20px" height="20px" />


//JavaScript for mouseoverevent

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#toolbar").hover(

  //on mouseover
    function() {
       $("#toolbar").animate({
          height: '550'
       }, 'slow');
    },

//on mouseout
   function() {
       $(this).animate({
         height: '-=500px'
       }, 'slow');
    }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick (i have not tested if it works for sure). It can be done for sure with a better way (maybe with toggle):

```
<img class="pin" height="20px" src="images/pin.png" width="20px"/>

//JavaScript for mouseoverevent
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isPinned = false;
  $(".pin").click(function(){
    $("#toolbar").css('height', '500px');
    isPinned = true;
  });


  $("#toolbar").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      if(!isPinned) {
          $("#toolbar").animate({
            height: '550'
          }, 'slow');
      }
    },

    //on mouseout
    function() {
      if(!isPinned) {
          $(this).animate({
            height: '-=500px'
          }, 'slow');
      }
    }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the onclick from the image and add this:

```
$('.pin').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('.pinned');
   if(parseInt($('#toolbar').css('height')) < 500) $("#toolbar").animate({
      height: '550'
   }, 'slow');
});
```

and edit the #toolbar hover function:

```
$("#toolbar").hover(
    function() {
       // return if its pinned
       if($('#toolbar .pin').hasClass('pinned')) return;
       $("#toolbar").animate({
          height: '550'
       }, 'slow');
    },

   function() {
       // return if its pinned
       if($('#toolbar .pin').hasClass('pinned')) return;
       $(this).animate({
         height: '-=500px'
       }, 'slow');
    }
    );
});
```

now you can use the .pinned class to visualize the state of the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Create a flag variable that stores the toolbar's state. Write a condition inside the mouseout function that bypasses the height change if the state is 'pinned'.